# Load function service in the same service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I'm trying to call a function elsewhere in the same service in AngularJS.

The function I'm calling in my controller is : geocoding, for the moment, all is ok.

But in my geocoding function, I'm calling another function : geovalue.

For now, the script say "geovalue is undefined".

Example of my code

```
app.service('geo', function(){

    this.geovalue = function(val, decimals){

        // some code & return a value at the end

    };

    this.geocoding = function(place, cb) {
        // some code
        my var = geovalue(val, decimals);
        // some code & return a valeu at the end

     };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geovalue` function is also `this`' method:

```
 my var = this.geovalue(val, decimals);
```

And seems like it should be:

```
 my var = this.geovalue(place, cb);
```